# How to change the creation date in domain registration record?

Tags: dns, web, whois

I'm interested to do it on domain  .com zone. Does anyone know a registrar which will be able to do it?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot change the creation date for your domain.  I assume that you wish to make your site seem older for SEO reasons.  That would be against ICANN policies.  However there is a meta tag that you can use to try to tell search engines how old your site is.

`<meta name="creation_Date" content="04/29/2010"/>`

Unfortunately for you, this is not used by many search engines (if any).  If you want to see what meta tags that Google uses, you can see a list [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812)

Answer (score 3):

The original creation date of the domain registration cannot be changed, per ICANN policy on this topic. All registrars are required to abide by the [ICANN WHOIS Accuracy clause](https://whois.icann.org/en/accuracy), which requires keeping track of the original domain creation date as long as that domain remains within their system. There used to be a loophole where Verisign would reset the creation date if a domain was transferred to them, but this has since disappeared since ICANN started requiring the original creation date to be sent to the accepting registrar in the event of a domain transfer. You can read more about these policies [here](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois-accuracy).

The only way to change the creation date in a domain registration record is to [allow the domain to expire, then be deleted](https://www.expireddomains.net/faq/). The domain can then be registered anew, thus resetting the creation date to a later date. However, this assumes that no one scoops up the domain name after it is deleted, and you are at risk of losing the domain name. While this is a way to move the creation date forward in time, there is no way to move the creation date backwards in time.

One of the reasons [this is enforced with domain name registrars](https://www.icann.org/public-comments/2013-whois-accuracy-spec-review-2015-05-14-en) is that it is swiftly becoming a part of case law. The domain name creation date can be used as evidence in defending trademarks in [selected cases](http://www.bitlaw.com/internet/domain.html).

You can learn more about the domain name registration process [here](https://whois.icann.org/en/domain-name-registration-process).

Comment: "if a domain was transferred to them"? how could that happen? VeriSign is the .COM/.NET registry among other things, so they handle a domain name because it is a .COM/.NET ones, or they do not if it is another TLD. So you can not transfer a domain name to a registry. You may confuse things with a registrar. Also, in some TLDs, the create date is indeed reset by a transfer. But not in gTLDs.